# How to tell cookiecutter to download a stable version of cookiecutter-django?

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter, cookiecutter-django

The command:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/
```

will clone the lastest version of `cookiecutter-django`, which is aimed for Django 1.9.

There is a [*Stable* section in the `README`](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django#releases) pointing to some tags. One of them being `https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/releases/tag/1.8.7`.

But if I try:

```
cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/releases/tag/1.8.7
```

I get an error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'git', u'clone', u'https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/releases/tag/1.8.7']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

So, how to specify `cookiecutter` to use those stable released instead of the `master` branch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [cookiecutter docs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#works-directly-with-git-and-hg-mercurial-repos-too), You can choose to checkout specific branch, tags and commit with CLI argument `--checkout` or `-c`

Something like this command should work:

```
$ cookiecutter https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django.git --checkout 1.8.7
```

Comment: This works for me. But it unveils a new problem: doing that after have used the template without the checkout option, cookiecutter warns you about I had colned cookiecutter-django.git, and propose me "to delete and re-clone it?".

So, it seems that I can't have both versiones of the same template (i.e cookiecutter-django).

Comment: Say 'yes' to delete and reclone. Then in the future if you want to use the latest cookiecutter-django, do the same.